# Autoregressive model problem with multiple dummy variables

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, arima, arma, intervention-analysis

I am conducting an event study, and I am trying to use dummy variables in my AR(4) model for stock returns to observe any abnormal returns.

Each dummy takes a value of 1 for one specific day, zero otherwise.

I have specified an AR(4) model for my series, and added 20 dummies, corresponding to -10 and +10 days to the event.  is the dummy for the event date.

However, I observe that standard errors get extremely large as going towards to -10.

also, coefficients and standard errors for dummies are different when adding 10 dummies (for -5 and +5 days). I can't understand why this is happening.

[image: for 10 dummies]

[image: for 20 dummies]

Comment: the model with 10 dummies is apparently different model than that with 20 dummies. why would you expect same coefficients ? also I did not understand how is the dummy constructed, what does it mean when SHIFT15=1 and what does it mean when SHIFT15=0 for example ?

Comment: the dummies are date dummies, so for example SHIFT01 takes value of 1 on the first day, zero otherwise, SHIFT02 takes value of 1 on the second day, zero otherwise, up to SHIFT20 for the 21st day. My model should be with 21 dummies, but I can't understand why standard errors increase so much when more dummies are added.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by "first day". first day of what ? first day of january ? first day of week - Monday ? or what exactly ? it confuses me your shift goes from -20 to +20 - does that mean is it past and future ? it also confuses me you have 21 days - what kind of period is this, I cant think of anything like that ? it seems to me it has something to do with the strange way you define your dummies, but somehow I did not get what you mean by your dummies at all.

Comment: Yes it is past and future -10 and +10 days. (So when the event date (shifta) is 7/15, the period is 7/5 (shift01) ~ 7/25 (shift20). My base model calculates normal returns, and each date dummy accounts for any abnormal returns on specific date.

Comment: Either I don't understand your model or it is "very strange". First you said "Each dummy takes a value of 1 for one specific day" and later you said "each date dummy accounts for any abnormal returns on specific date". So I would suggest to clarify to yourself what it really measures - whether a day or an abnormal return.

Comment: But the weirdest is that, if I understood correctly, the SHIFTA variable relate to the same information you are trying to predict and the SHIFT0...SHIFT20 relate even to future values which is like you have a "time machine" somewhere. Sorry I cant give any specific explanation of your standard errors but I would recommend to re-think your model structure entirely and the problem will disappear hopefully.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I should have said that the coefficient of each dummy accounts for the abnormal returns of each day. Each dummy indeed takes a value of 1 for each day

Comment: anyway I still think the model makes no sense as you are using present and future information to predict past. therefore I don't even see it as a valuable question.

Comment: please note that I am conducting an 'event study'. there is an event date in the past, and +10 is not a future value but another past value. I am not making any predictions, Im just seeing whether the event that I am researching had an impact in the past. Adding dummy variables for the event window is a standard event study btw.